WMS Layer does not load on ios
We're using rnmapbox/maps in our react-native project. After updating from a very old version 10.0.0-rc.0 to 10.1.20 the loading of the WMS layers we are using in the map broke for ios. It works perfectly fine for android.
On ios it does neither work in the simulator nor on the device itself.
The errors we get in the simulator (ios 17.2):
[MapboxCommon] [Error, maps-core]: {}[Style]: Failed to load tile 14/8648/5733=>14 for source rasterSource:
[MapboxCommon] [Error, maps-core]: {}[Style]: Failed to load tile 14/8648/5734=>14 for source rasterSource:
 ERROR  Mapbox [error] MapLoad error Failed to load tile:
 ERROR  Mapbox [error] MapLoad error Failed to load tile:
[MapboxCommon] [Error, maps-core]: {}[Style]: Failed to load tile 15/17298/11466=>15 for source rasterSource:
[MapboxCommon] [Error, maps-core]: {}[Style]: Failed to load tile 15/17297/11466=>15 for source rasterSource:
 ERROR  Mapbox [error] MapLoad error Failed to load tile:
 ERROR  Mapbox [error] MapLoad error Failed to load tile:

This is how we add the WMS source to the map inside the Mapview component:
<MapboxGL.RasterSource
          key="rasterSource"
          id="rasterSource"
          tileSize={256}
          tileUrlTemplates={[
            'https://vogis.cnv.at/mapserver/mapserv?map=i_luftbilder_r_wms.map&service=WMS&request=GetMap&version=1.3.0&crs=EPSG:3857&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=ef2022_10cm&width=256&height=256&transparent=true',
          ]}
        >
  <MapboxGL.RasterLayer id="rasterLayer" sourceID="rasterSource" style="" />
</MapboxGL.RasterSource>

Anyone experienced a similar issue or has any idea what could be the underlying problem?
